# Redirecting to Edit page when clicked on a edit button on a table row

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I am creating an admin page for my employee extension list project. I have put Edit and delete buttons next to every row. Code is as below:

```
<table id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th style="width: 175px" >First Name</th>
                <th style="width: 175px" >Extension</th>
                <th id="locHead" class=">Location</th>
                <th style="width: 175px" >Cell</th>
                <th id="teamHead" class=">Team(s)</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <%
            List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>();

            PhoneListController controller = new PhoneListController();
            list = controller.getAllContacts();
            for (Employee e : list) {

            %>              
            <tr>
                <td id="lastName"></td>
                <td style="width: 175px"><%=e.getFirst()%></td>
                <td style="width: 135px"><%=e.getExt()%></td>
                <td><%=e.getLoc()%></td>
                <td style="width: 175px"><%=e.getCell()%></td>
                <td ><%=e.getTeam()%></td>                  
                <td style="border: none; width: 50px">
                        <div>
                            <form method="post" action="empUpdate.jsp">
                                <input type="hidden" id="updateId" name="updateId" value="<%=e.getRecNo()%>"/> 
                                <input type="submit" value="Modify" onclick="document.location.href='EditEmployee.jsp';"/> 
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td style="border: none; width: 50px">
                        <div>
                            <form method="post" action="DeleteServlet">
                                <input type="hidden" id="delId" name="delId" value="<%=e.getRecNo()%>"/> 
                                <input type="submit" value="Delete"/> 
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </td>
            </tr>

            <%
                }
            %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

In the last two  elements I have my modify and delete buttons. When I click on modify button, I am expecting to be redirected to edit page with data being prefilled in the fields acc to recNo. But it simply doesn't do anything. Can anyone suggest where I m doing wrong? Is there any other way I can accomplish this? I am using jsp servlets.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I had to put method="get" rather than post. That solved the problem.